# Spark: Hive Query

Tags: hive, apache-spark, hiveql, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have a log file, and the first column would be my partition in Hive table.

```
    logSchemaRDD.registerTempTable("logs")

    hiveContext.sql("insert overwrite table logs_parquet PARTITION(create_date=select ? from logs) select * from logs")
```

How do I construct the query to select the first column (marked as ? here) and ensure that the one I selected in partition matches the 2nd select (*)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly enumerate the columns in both the source and target list: in this case select * will not suffice.

```
insert overwrite table logs_parquet PARTITION(create_date) (col2, col3..) 
select col2,col3, .. col1 from logs
```

Yes it is more work to write the query - but partitioning queries do require the explicit mapping of the columns ***with the partitioning columns last***.